# Splitting a multipage TIFF image into individual images (Java)

Tags: java, tiff

Been tearing my hair on this one.

How do I split a multipage / multilayer TIFF image into several individual images?

Demo image available [here](http://www.csc.kth.se/~landreas/multipage.tiff).

(Would prefer a pure Java (i.e. non-native) solution. Doesn't matter if the solution relies on commercial libraries.)

Comment: If your TIFF files will be consistent and like the sample, you can do a quick-n-dirty method which is not hard to write. A generalized routine to handle all TIFFs would be more complicated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the **Java Advanced Imaging** library, [JAI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/current-142188.html), to split a mutlipage TIFF, by using an ImageReader:

```
ImageInputStream is = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new File(pathToImage));
if (is == null || is.length() == 0){
  // handle error
}
Iterator<ImageReader> iterator = ImageIO.getImageReaders(is);
if (iterator == null || !iterator.hasNext()) {
  throw new IOException("Image file format not supported by ImageIO: " + pathToImage);
}
// We are just looking for the first reader compatible:
ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) iterator.next();
iterator = null;
reader.setInput(is);
```

Then you can get the number of pages:

```
nbPages = reader.getNumImages(true);
```

and read pages separatly:

```
reader.read(numPage)
```

Comment: Actually, a great thing about the code you posted, is that it doesn't even require JAI at compile time, and JAI may be substituted for another TIFF plugin at run time. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I used this sample above with a tiff plugin i found called imageio-tiff.

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.tomgibara.imageio</groupId>
        <artifactId>imageio-tiff</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I was able to get the buffered images from a tiff resource:

```
   Resource img3 = new ClassPathResource(TIFF4);
            ImageInputStream is = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(img3.getInputStream());

            Iterator<ImageReader> iterator = ImageIO.getImageReaders(is);
            if (iterator == null || !iterator.hasNext()) {
                throw new IOException("Image file format not supported by ImageIO: ");
            }
            // We are just looking for the first reader compatible:
            ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) iterator.next();
            iterator = null;
            reader.setInput(is);
            int nbPages = reader.getNumImages(true);

            LOGGER.info("No. of pages for tiff file is {}", nbPages);
  BufferedImage image1 = reader.read(0);
        BufferedImage image2 = reader.read(1);
        BufferedImage image3 = reader.read(2);
```

But then i found another project called apache commons imaging
Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-imaging</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

In one line you can get the buffered images:

```
 List<BufferedImage> bufferedImages = Imaging.getAllBufferedImages(img3.getInputStream(), TIFF4);
        LOGGER.info("No. of pages for tiff file is {} using apache commons imaging", bufferedImages.size());
```

Then write to file sample:

```
 final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        // set optional parameters if you like
        params.put(ImagingConstants.PARAM_KEY_COMPRESSION, new Integer(TiffConstants.TIFF_COMPRESSION_CCITT_GROUP_4));
        int i = 0;
        for (Iterator<BufferedImage> iterator1 = bufferedImages.iterator(); iterator1.hasNext(); i++) {
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = iterator1.next();
            LOGGER.info("Image type  {}", bufferedImage.getType());
            File outFile = new File("C:\\tmp" + File.separator + "shane" + i + ".tiff");
            Imaging.writeImage(bufferedImage, outFile, ImageFormats.TIFF, params);
        }
```

Actually testing performance, apache is alot slower...

Or use an old version of iText, which is alot faster:

```
private ByteArrayOutputStream convertTiffToPdf(InputStream imageStream) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Image image;
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
    writer.setStrictImageSequence(true);
    document.open();

    RandomAccessFileOrArray ra = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(imageStream);
    int pages = TiffImage.getNumberOfPages(ra);
    for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++) {
        image = TiffImage.getTiffImage(ra, i);
        image.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
        image.scaleToFit(PageSize.A4.getWidth(), PageSize.A4.getHeight());
        document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
        document.newPage();
        document.add(image);
    }
    document.close();
    out.flush();
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A fast but non JAVA solution is `tiffsplit`. It is part of the libtiff library.

An example command to split a tiff file in all it's layers would be:

`tiffsplit image.tif`

The manpage says it all:

```
NAME
       tiffsplit - split a multi-image TIFF into single-image TIFF files

SYNOPSIS
       tiffsplit src.tif [ prefix ]

DESCRIPTION
       tiffsplit  takes  a multi-directory (page) TIFF file and creates one or more single-directory (page) TIFF files
       from it.  The output files are given names created by concatenating a prefix, a lexically ordered suffix in the
       range  [aaa-zzz],  the  suffix  .tif (e.g.  xaaa.tif, xaab.tif, xzzz.tif).  If a prefix is not specified on the
       command line, the default prefix of x is used.

OPTIONS
       None.

BUGS
       Only a select set of ‘‘known tags’’ is copied when splitting.

SEE ALSO
       tiffcp(1), tiffinfo(1), libtiff(3TIFF)

       Libtiff library home page: http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did it with ImageIO:

```
public List<BufferedImage> extractImages(InputStream fileInput) throws Exception {
    List<BufferedImage> extractedImages = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();

    try (ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(fileInput)) {

        ImageReader reader = getTiffImageReader();
        reader.setInput(iis);

        int pages = reader.getNumImages(true);
        for (int imageIndex = 0; imageIndex < pages; imageIndex++) {
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = reader.read(imageIndex);
            extractedImages.add(bufferedImage);
        }
    }

    return extractedImages;
}

private ImageReader getTiffImageReader() {
    Iterator<ImageReader> imageReaders = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("TIFF");
    if (!imageReaders.hasNext()) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No TIFF Reader found!");
    }
    return imageReaders.next();
}
```

I took part of the code from [this blog](http://www.pagu.at/blog/multi-page-tiff-handling-with-imageio/).

Answer (score 2):

All the proposed solutions require reading the multipage image page by page and write the pages back to new TIFF images. Unless you want to save the individual pages to different image format, there is no point in decoding the image. Given the special structure of the TIFF image, you can split a multipage TIFF into single TIFF images without decoding.

The TIFF tweaking tool (part of a larger image related library - ["icafe"](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe/wiki) I am using is written from scratch with pure Java. It can delete pages, insert pages, retain certain pages, split pages from a multiple page TIFF as well as merge multipage TIFF images into one TIFF image without decompressing them.

After trying with the TIFF tweaking tool, I am able to split the image into 3 pages: [page#0](https://www.dropbox.com/s/retgge59p48vsak/page_%230.tif), [page#1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rvwier6gqmeh7u1/page_%231.tif), and [page#2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wwf4w2rfm86o8l9/page_%232.tif)

**NOTE1:** The original demo image for some reason contains "incorrect" StripByteCounts value 1 which is not the actual bytes needed for the images strip. It turns out that the image data are not compressed, so the actual bytes for each image strip could be figured out through other TIFF field values such as RowsPerStrip, SamplesPerPixel, ImageWidth, etc.

**NOTE2:** Since in splitting the TIFF, the above mentioned library doesn't need to decode and re-encode the image. So it's fast and it also keeps the original encoding and additional metadata of each pages!

Answer (score 0):

The below code will convert the multiple tiff into individual's and produces an Excel sheet with list of tiff images.

You need to create a folder in the C drive and place your TIFF images into it then run this code.

Need to import the below jars.

> 1.sun-as-jsr88-dm-4.0-sources
>
> 2./sun-jai_codec
>
> 3.sun-jai_core

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.awt.image.renderable.ParameterBlock;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.media.jai.JAI;
import javax.media.jai.RenderedOp;

import com.sun.media.jai.codec.FileSeekableStream;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageCodec;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageDecoder;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.TIFFEncodeParam;

import java.io.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class TIFF_Sepreator {

    File folder = new File("C:/FAX/"); 
    
    
public static void infoBox(String infoMessage, String titleBar)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage, "InfoBox: " + titleBar, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    
public void  splitting() throws IOException, AWTException 
    {       
        boolean FinalFAXFolder = (new File("C:/Final_FAX")).mkdirs();
        
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        String dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                
   try{
        if (listOfFiles.length > 0)
        {
            for(int file=0; file<listOfFiles.length; file++)
            {
            System.out.println(listOfFiles[file]);
            FileSeekableStream ss = new FileSeekableStream(listOfFiles[file]);
            ImageDecoder dec = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("tiff", ss, null);
            int count = dec.getNumPages();
            TIFFEncodeParam param = new TIFFEncodeParam();
            param.setCompression(TIFFEncodeParam.COMPRESSION_GROUP4);
            param.setLittleEndian(false); // Intel
            System.out.println("This TIF has " + count + " image(s)");
        
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
                {
                    RenderedImage page = dec.decodeAsRenderedImage(i);
                    File f = new File("C:\\Final_FAX\\"+dateFormat+ file +i + ".tif");
                    System.out.println("Saving " + f.getCanonicalPath());
                    ParameterBlock pb = new ParameterBlock();
                    pb.addSource(page);
                    pb.add(f.toString());
                    pb.add("tiff");
                    pb.add(param);
                    RenderedOp r = JAI.create("filestore",pb);
                    r.dispose();
                }
            }
            TIFF_Sepreator.infoBox("Find your splitted TIFF images in location 'C:/Final_FAX/' " , "Done :)");
            WriteListOFFilesIntoExcel();
        }  
  
        else
        {
            TIFF_Sepreator.infoBox("No files was found in location 'C:/FAX/' " , "Empty folder");
            System.out.println("No files found");
        }
    } 
   
   catch(Exception e)
   
        {
            TIFF_Sepreator.infoBox("Unabe to run due to this  error: " +e , "Error");
            System.out.println("Error: "+e);
        }
    }

public void WriteListOFFilesIntoExcel(){
    
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(folder.listFiles()));
    
    
    try {
    String filename = "C:/Final_FAX/List_Of_Fax_Files.xls" ;
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("FirstSheet"); 
    
    for (int file=0; file<listOfFiles.length; file++) {
        System.out.println(listOfFiles[file]);
           Row r = sheet.createRow(file);
           r.createCell(0).setCellValue(files.get(file).toString());
        }

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    workbook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
    System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");
    
    }
 catch(Exception ex){
        TIFF_Sepreator.infoBox("Unabe to run due to this  error: " +ex , "Error");
        System.out.println("Error: "+ex);   
 }
}
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, AWTException {
         new TIFF_Sepreator().splitting();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works to set the compression to `default param.setCompression(32946);`.

```html
public static void  doitJAI(String mutitiff) throws IOException {
  FileSeekableStream ss = new FileSeekableStream(mutitiff);
  ImageDecoder dec = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("tiff", ss, null);
  int count = dec.getNumPages();
  TIFFEncodeParam param = new TIFFEncodeParam();
  param.setCompression(32946);
  param.setLittleEndian(false); // Intel
  System.out.println("This TIF has " + count + " image(s)");
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      RenderedImage page = dec.decodeAsRenderedImage(i);
      File f = new File("D:/PSN/SCB/SCAN/bin/Debug/Temps/test/single_" + i + ".tif");
      System.out.println("Saving " + f.getCanonicalPath());
      ParameterBlock pb = new ParameterBlock();
      pb.addSource(page);
      pb.add(f.toString());
      pb.add("tiff");
      pb.add(param);
      RenderedOp r = JAI.create("filestore",pb);
      r.dispose();
  }
}
```