# Android view multi page .tiff file

Tags: android, android-ndk, tiff

I am using this [tiffonandroid library](https://code.google.com/p/tiffonandroid/) to view `.tiff` images in my Android application and its working fine.

The problem however is that some of the `.tiff` files I receive from server are multi page `.tiff` files and the above library provides a means to view only one page (the front page) although that `.tiff` file has other pages.

How can I display multi page `.tiff` files using the above library?

Comment: There are a few solutions to splitting a multi-page file into individual images here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770071/splitting-a-multipage-tiff-image-into-individual-images-java. You could then handle them however you wish.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link, do you have any idea on how to call native tiffsplit function from libtiff library ?

Answer (score 1):

I create library that allows read multipage tiffs https://github.com/Beyka/Android-TiffBitmapFactory