# What is solution for read file tiff with multiple in android?

Tags: android, c++, tiff

I have a plan reading file tiff in android. Yet, if the file tiff has pages, I can’t find solution. Plesea tell me if you have any idea.

what i have done :

- I know that it can read the file tiff with only one page

https://code.google.com/p/tiffonandroid/][1]

- try give it a try But I’m not successful and even it happens  I can hard  know how to use it in android

[Splitting a multipage TIFF image into individual images (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770071/splitting-a-multipage-tiff-image-into-individual-images-java)

Comment: Do you need to process the image data or just display it? If just to display it, you can send an intent to my app "Fast Image Viewer". There's a free version and it supports multi-page TIFF and a lot of other formats.

Comment: oh no. i must be make one application to display tiff file. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try my library that allow to choose some decode parameters https://github.com/Beyka/Android-TiffBitmapFactory

Comment: okey i finish my application to read tiff file. so thank for rep. how can i contact to you ( gmail, facebook, skypes...) ?

Comment: leshabey@gmail.com or skype leshabey

Comment: any way to do it without external libraries ?